# OpenCV crop returns 0:0

Tags: python

Im tring to resize and crop image using opencv but when I try to crop it Im getting image size 0,0?

```
resized = imutils.resize(image2, width=100)

cv2.imshow("original2", resized)
cv2.waitKey()

w = resized.shape[1]
h = resized.shape[0]
min_dimension = min(w, h)
w_crop = min_dimension
h_crop = min_dimension

print("<<<>>>",0,":",0,"<>",w_crop,":",h_crop)

cropped = resized[0:0, h_crop:w_crop]

print(cropped.shape)

cv2.imshow("original3", cropped)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: I'd image `w` or `h` is zero, then? Add `print(image2.shape, resized.shape)`...

Comment: I check by printing them out in <<<>>> part of the code and the w_crop and h_crop are 100 as they should be as thats the minimal value from image shape,

Comment: I also tried to crop the image .. manually by writing something like cropped=resized[0:0, 10:50] and get the same. printing out resized.shape gets me 0,0,3

Comment: Then I imagine that cropping syntax is wrong.

Comment: acording to https://pysource.com/2021/03/04/how-crop-images-with-opencv-and-python/ the sintax is # Cut image
cut_image = img[426: 853, 0: 1280]

Comment: crap, i mixed the values it should be cropped = resized[0:100, 0:100]

Answer (score 1):

crap, i mixed the values it should be cropped = resized[0:100, 0:100]